# how to get the value of products using on function in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, this

want to use a Javascript function that would get the price of the value of the product and add it to an existing value on click of the button every time
using the "THIS" keyword to get those value of the price.
and it would be nice if there is a clear explanation for "THIS" keyword

```js
var total = document.getElementById('total');
var price = document.getElementById('price').value
var quantity = document.getElementById('quantity').value;

var i = 0;
var totalPrice = 0;
function add() {
  i++
  totalPrice = Number(this.totalPrice) + Number(this.price);
  total.innerHTML = "Total Price: " + totalPrice;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6 ">
    <img src="Products/blackberry.jpg" class="product_pics" />
    <h3 id="name">Blackberry</h3>
    50,000 <input type="number" name="" id="price" value="50000"><br> Quantity <input type="number" name="quantity" id="quantity" min="1" max="50">
    <button class="AddtoCart" onclick="add(this)">ADD TO CART</button>
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <img src="Products/iphone5.jpeg" class="product_pics" />
    <h3 id="name">IPHONE 3</h3>
    100,000 <input type="number" name="" id="price" value="100000"><br> Quantity <input type="number" name="quantity" id="quantity" min="1" max="50">
    <button class="AddtoCart" onclick="add(this)">ADD TO CART</button>
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <img src="Products/iphone6.jpg" class="product_pics" />
    <h3 id="name">IPHONE 6</h3>
    90,000 <input type="number" name="" id="price" value="90000"><br> Quantity <input type="number" name="quantity" id="quantity" min="1" max="50">
    <button class="AddtoCart" onclick="add(this)">ADD TO CART</button>
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <img src="Products/samsung.jpg" class="product_pics" />
    <h3 id="name">IPHONE 6</h3>
    250,000 <input type="number" name="" id="price" value="250000"><br> Quantity <input type="number" name="quantity" id="quantity" min="1" max="50">
    <button class="AddtoCart" onclick="add(this)">ADD TO CART</button>
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <img src="Products/3.png" class="product_pics" />
    <h3 id="name">Red band WristWatch</h3>
    10,000 <input type="number" name="" id="price" value="10000"><br> Quantity <input type="number" name="quantity" id="quantity" min="1" max="50">
    <button class="AddtoCart" onclick="add(this)">ADD TO CART</button>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6 ">
    <img src="Products/2.JPG" class="product_pics" />
    <h3 id="name">Female wrist Watch</h3>
    250,000 <input type="number" name="" id="price" value="250000"><br> Quantity <input type="number" name="quantity" id="quantity" min="1" max="50">
    <button class="AddtoCart" onclick="add(this)">ADD TO CART</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You are missing a div or span called total

Comment: It there actually forgot to post the code

Comment: also you cannot use `this` in the function since you are PASSING the object instead of assigning add to the event Also the `this.totalPrice` and `this.price` you are interested in is not available to the button

Comment: so what do i do?

Answer (score 0):

1. you forgot total span
2. `this.totalPrice` and `this.price` you are interested in is not available to the button
3. You need UNIQUE IDs but I am using class instead

You may want this:

```js
var total = document.getElementById('total');

var totalPrice = 0;

function add() {
  var qs = document.querySelectorAll(".quantity");
  var price = document.querySelectorAll(".price"); // assuming one of each
  var totalPrice = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < qs.length; i++) {
    var q = qs[i].value;
    q = isNaN(q) || q.trim() == "" ? 0 : parseInt(q); // make sure it's a number
    if (q) {
      totalPrice += q * price[i].value; // grab the value from the corresponding price
    }
    document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = "Total Price: " + totalPrice.toFixed(2);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6 ">
    <img src="Products/blackberry.jpg" class="product_pics" />
    <h3 id="name">Blackberry</h3>
    50,000 <input type="number" name="bb" class="price" value="50000"><br> Quantity <input type="number" name="quantity" class="quantity" min="0" max="50" value="0">
    <button class="AddtoCart" onclick="add()">ADD TO CART</button>
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <img src="Products/iphone5.jpeg" class="product_pics" />
    <h3 id="name">IPHONE 5</h3>
    100,000 <input type="number" name="iphone5" class="price" value="100000"><br> Quantity <input type="number" name="quantity" class="quantity" min="0" max="50" value="0">
    <button class="AddtoCart" onclick="add()">ADD TO CART</button>
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <img src="Products/iphone6.jpg" class="product_pics" />
    <h3 id="name">IPHONE 6</h3>
    90,000 <input type="number" name="iphone6" class="price" value="90000"><br> Quantity <input type="number" name="quantity" class="quantity" min="0" max="50" value="0">
    <button class="AddtoCart" onclick="add()">ADD TO CART</button>
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <img src="Products/samsung.jpg" class="product_pics" />
    <h3 id="name">Samsung</h3>
    250,000 <input type="number" name="Samsung" class="price" value="250000"><br> Quantity <input type="number" name="quantity" class="quantity" min="0" max="50" value="0">
    <button class="AddtoCart" onclick="add()">ADD TO CART</button>
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <img src="Products/3.png" class="product_pics" />
    <h3 id="name">Red band WristWatch</h3>
    10,000 <input type="number" name="ww" class="price" value="10000"><br> Quantity <input type="number" name="quantity" class="quantity" min="0" max="50" value="0">
    <button class="AddtoCart" onclick="add()">ADD TO CART</button>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6 ">
    <img src="Products/2.JPG" class="product_pics" />
    <h3 id="name">Female wrist Watch</h3>
    250,000 <input type="number" name="fmw" class="price" value="250000"><br> Quantity <input type="number" name="quantity" class="quantity" min="0" max="50" value="0">
    <button class="AddtoCart" onclick="add()">ADD TO CART</button>
  </div>
</div>
<span id="total"></span>
```